# Need help about turning of Etag for specific url via htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, etag

I'd like to turn off Etag for all xxx.googleapis.com

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&ver=3.9.1
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900&ver=1406918262
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=panoramio&language=en&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps
http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en&lyrs=m%40270000000%7Csalt%3A185418970&las=twutvtvvttwv,twutvtvvttww,twutvtvvtuvv,twutvtvvtuvw,twutvtvvtvut,twutvtvvtvuu,twutvtvvtvuv,twutvtvvtvuw,twutvtvvtvwt,twutvtvvtvwu,twutvtvvtvwv,twutvtvvtvww,twutvtvvtwtt,twutvtvvtwtu,twutvtvvtwtv,twutvtvvtwtw,twutvtvvtwvt,twutvtvvtwvu,twutvtvvtwvv,twutvtvvtwvw,twutvtvvvtut,twutvtvvvtuu,twutvtvvvutt,twutvtvvvutu&z=12&src=apiv3&xc=1&style=47%2C37%7Csmartmaps&apistyle=p.h%3A%23ff1a00%7Cp.il%3Atrue%7Cp.s%3A-100%7Cp.l%3A33%7Cp.g%3A0.5%2Cs.t%3A6%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ff2D333C&callback=_xdc_._dpwvne&token=112829
```

Here is what I try but it doesn't work

```
<FilesMatch "(/^http?:\/\/([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.){0,}googleapis\.com$/)”>
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

What's wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$` at the end of your expression, which tells the regex parser that this is the end of the line.  If you'd like to capture URL's that contain data after `.com`, remove the `$`.

Like this:

```
<FilesMatch "(/^http?:\/\/([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.){0,}googleapis\.com/)”>
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It seems to work but I still got this notice http://imgur.com/v29jEQd

Any idea?

Comment: `FilesMatch` cannot match full URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_setenvif` here:

```
# set env=NO_ETAG for certain URIs
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+googleapis\.com/" NO_ETAG

# use that env variable to set headers
Header unset ETag env=NO_ETAG
```